# Redirect homepage ( www.sitename.com ) to the latest post

Tags: redirect

I'm just wondering how I would go about redirecting to the latest post when you go to the web site? Similar to http://gregorywood.co.uk/

Many thanks :)

Suleiman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (as plugin or theme's functions.php):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect' );
function redirect() {
        if ( is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : 
                wp_redirect( get_permalink() , 301 ); 
                exit; 
        endif;
}
```